Tailwind CSS styles not rendering in Svelte app
I have setup a svelte app using "npm create vite@latest" choosing to use Svelte and TypeScript. I'm using Vite as the server, and I have also installed TailWind CSS per the instructions here.
My tailwind.config.cjs code:
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ['./webapp/**/*.{svelte,html,ts}'],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}

My current app.css code:
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

I've created a routes folder within the src folder which code is:
<script>
  import "../app.css";
</script>

<slot />

I keep receiving this error:
warn - The `content` option in your Tailwind CSS configuration is missing or empty.
warn - Configure your content sources or your generated CSS will be missing styles.
warn - https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration

I've stopped the server and ran it again, with the same issues. I've checked the content directory a million times, even trying to use specific file paths. I can't seem to get it to work. Can anyone help me out with this? I've included an image of my working folder, as well. I really appreciate any insight given. working folder
More or less described above; I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong after reading a lot of documentation and watching countless videos. The developers I'm working with are using Svelte, TS, and Tailwind CSS, otherwise I would try a different approach.

Since you have Vite in the webapp folder, that would be the "root" of the project in terms of its build/compilation. Consider moving the postcss.config.js and tailwind.config.cjs into the webapp folder.
Then, consider changing the content paths in tailwind.config.cjs to something like:
module.exports = {
  content: ['./src/**/*.{svelte,html,ts}'],

Ensure you run the vite command from within the webapp folder.

perfect! Thank you so much for your quick and concise solution. I'm pretty new to using Tailwind with Svelte, and this worked perfectly! Thank you, thank you, you are my hero!
